# Run selenium tests by using xml file in JAVA as imported

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-ide

I want to run selenium tests by using xml file which is produced by Firefox Selenium IDE, in JAVA. Assume that we generate xml file from Selenium IDE. After this generation it is need to run this recorded test as xml, in JAVA. 
Is there a way to import this xml file and run as JAVA code without parsing? Actually I want to JAVA to understand as selenium test and run.

Thank!

Comment: Isn't it possible to use the build-in option of Selenium IDE to export the recorded script to JUnit, or do you really need to export it to an XML file?

Comment: Assume that i don't export from IDE. Someone send it to me as XML file an I should import and run it in JAVA

Comment: I don't think this functionality exists in Selenium at the moment, but you could look at the javascript source of the IDE to build your own parser. 
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fide%2Fplugins%2Fjava-format%2Fsrc%2Fcontent%2Fformats

Answer (score 0):

- In Firefox install Selenium IDE add-ons.
- Open that xml file in Selenium IDE.
- Now in Selenium IDE, Select "File >> Export Test Case As >> JUnit 4 (Remote Control)/JUnit 3 (Remote Control)" options.
- Save that Script as .java file
- Then You can run that .java script file in Eclipse.

Comment: It won't be exporeted as JAVA-JUnit, actually i wont export it too. The scripts will be prepared as XML or XHTML and sent to me. I need to import these selenium xml scripts in JAVA and run them as selenium test.